# How to declare Inputs on a component in Angular 2 in ES5?

Tags: angular

Angular2's current documentation doesn't provide an example for using `@Input` and `@Output` in es5 syntax.

I'm trying to get an angular2 fiddle up so need to use es5

This is the es2016 version

```
class BankAccount {
  @Input() bankName: string;
  @Input('account-id') id: string;
  // this property is not bound, and won't be automatically updated by Angular
  normalizedBankName: string;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`inputs`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L467) and [`outputs`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.44/modules/angular2/src/core/metadata/directives.ts#L520) properties in `Component` annotation. See [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AEGsR1VZtAqiYNt12yiI?p=preview).

```js
var BankAccount = ng
  .Component({
    selector: 'bank-account',
    template: '<b>{{ bankName }}<b><span>{{ id }}',
    inputs: [
      'bankName', 
      'id: accountId'
    ]
  })
  .Class({
    constructor: function() {
      this.bankName = null;
      this.id = null;
    }
  });
```

Comment: How to implement it in HTML? Something like this: <bank-account id="1"></bank-account>

Comment: Check Plunkr mentioned in the answer. You should use `<bank-account [accountId]="someProperty"></bank-account>`. In the expample the alpha version of angular2 is used and there you should use `account-id` instead of `accountId`

Comment: Can you show an example of its usage too. This is so useful.

Comment: I also would like to know how to pass data into a component from plain HTML. The Plunkr mentioned in the answer calls the `<bank-account>` component from a parent component.